# RabbitMQ Management Plugin vs. AMQP

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I wish to programmatically  manage exchanges, queues, bindings, and view resource usage of my rabbitmq server. I can do all these by making REST API calls made available by [rabbitmq management plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html). However, is it possible to achieve all that using AMQP protocol instead of using the management plugin? In other words, will an AMQP client allow me to do everything that the management plugin does?

If there is no alternative, is there any performance concern if I enable and use the management plugin?

Comment: You should have added which language client you are planning to use. I have been using Java RabbiMQ client and it does allow me to create/declare exchange, create queue and bind a queue with exchange. For this simple use case, i believe the management plugin is over kill.

Comment: I did not specify any language on purpose, as I was trying to ask if AMQP 0.9.1 protocol itself supports everything that rabbitmq management plugin is capable of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AMQP 0.9.1 does not have any way of discovery or listing of queues and exchanges. Management plugin, on the other hand, has APIs such as `GET /api/exchanges` and `GET /api/queues`. Due to this requirement, management plugin was my only solution.

Answer (score 0):

In theory someone could implement a way that all the info is delivered via an AMQP queue. But it would have to be so that no consumer should ACK any of the messages because then they would be gone from the queue and the publisher would have to figure this out and publish the same thing again. In other words, it shouldn't be done.
Also it would be semantically (?) wrong, since AMQP by it's nature is designed with flowing/changing/dynamic data in mind, and all this data about resources, queues etc is static (and in some cases meta) info.

No performance concerns (in this context of course).

Additionally you can also use the command line tool if it's more comfortable